# How to extend MVC 4 authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We are using the default MVC 4 template that came with VS 2012 (C#) and we like that we have user registration and authentication out of the box. Now we need to extend this functionality by:

1. Allowing users to change their initial username and email address
   (currently, they can change only password);
2. Adding extra fields related to the user, such as display name, country, etc. about the
   same user so they have an extended profile on our site.

We looked around the Internet and there are so many articles but non of them fits our 2 points above. Maybe because it's a simple questions.

Any link to an article, a tutorial, or a post here will help a lot!

Comment: This question is a [bit broad (faq)](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) and ambiguous because there are multiple ways of doing this.  It would be easier (at least for me) to help you if you have some code to diagnose a problem.  If you're asking for a best practice I would highly suggest asking this question on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Hey Erik! We have many user profile properties in another DB (secondary DB) and link them to the user in the MembershipProvider by Username (main DB). Regretably, our users want to change her usernames. We can do that in the secondary DB but not in the MembershipUser. So, how do we change the username in the authentication table?